# Unable to create Mailchimp template through API

Tags: php, drupal, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to create a new Template in MailChimp using API V3.0 from my Drupal application (http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/templates/#create-post_templates). I'm providing the **name** and **html** parameters in my request body as these two are the only mandatory fields. I'm unsure of the correct format of html which I need to send, so I've followed the below steps.

1. Created a new template in MailChimp using the template builder (https://us12.admin.mailchimp.com/templates/create-template/)
2. Exported this template as HTML and then send it as string in my request.

I keep on getting the below error once I make the call.

**json_encode error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded**